# How to check if a user name already exists with pouchdb-authentication?

Tags: authentication, couchdb, pouchdb

#### Context below.

The [pouchdb-authentication API](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-authentication/blob/master/docs/api.md) doesn't offer an explicit method for this. I thought about using [`db.getUser(username [, opts][, callback])`](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-authentication/blob/master/docs/api.md#dbgetuserusername--opts-callback). This method states however:

> Note: Only server admins or the user themselves can fetch user data. Otherwise you will get a 404 not_found error.

which I do.

### Context

I want to use an asynchronous validator to check whether a username exists or not so that I can tell the user if the username exists or not before they click 'submit'.

The only other alternative I can think of is trying to register to find out if the username already exists like so:

[image]

Comment: I'm curious, are you using PouchDB on frontend/browser JavaScript code or are you employing PouchDB on backend/NodeJS JavaScript code?

Comment: The normal setup - CouchDB on the backend and PouchDB on the front. The two sync with each other

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if PouchDB doesn't have such a feature, you can implement it with CouchDB itself. Here is HTTP GET request with admin credentials which returns all users:

```
$ curl -u admin:admin -X GET http://localhost:5984/_users/_all_docs
{"total_rows":4,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"_design/_auth","key":"_design/_auth","value":{"rev":"1-75efcce1f083316d622d389f3f9813f7"}},
{"id":"org.couchdb.user:admin","key":"org.couchdb.user:admin","value":{"rev":"1-c363450b879aaf64823901816b5690db"}},
{"id":"org.couchdb.user:su","key":"org.couchdb.user:su","value":{"rev":"1-c468424e1e3cc6b76baca17a9a3b7a26"}},
{"id":"org.couchdb.user:suser","key":"org.couchdb.user:suser","value":{"rev":"1-1b0c0623016feb5a5d701b392b60ad84"}}
]}
```

---

For example, using NodeJS/ExressJS on the server side, you can send a HTTP GET request with admin credentials to CouchDB and get a list of all users. HTTP request can be done with [node-fetch](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch).

At the same time, NodeJS/ExpressJS receives the value of `username` input field from front-end, by a HTTP POST request. On front-end you can use [browser fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

Then you can compare if the value inside `username` input field is among the users. Based on the comparison, you can send a response back to frontend/browser. Fetch API uses [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which makes all the HTTP communications asynchronous.

---

As pointed out by @BernhardGschwantner it is a better idea to first `fetch` the username from frontend/browser and then query that username by a HTTP request to CouchDB to see if the user exists.

To make HTTP request to CouchDB, you can make a HEAD request which is expected to be even faster than GET request. If user exists, HTTP HEAD request returns `200 OK` along with the revision of user document inside `ETag` like below:

```
$ curl -I -X HEAD http://admin:****@192.168.1.106:5984/_users/org.couchdb.user:jan
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-CouchDB-Body-Time: 0
X-Couch-Request-ID: fbae21471c
Server: CouchDB/2.1.1 (Erlang OTP/18)
ETag: "3-f11b227a6e1236fa502af668fdbf326d"
Date: Fri, 30 Mar 2018 08:29:55 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 263
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
```

If user does NOT exist, the HTTP HEAD request returns `404 Object Not Found` without any `ETag`, like below:

```
$ curl -I -X HEAD http://admin:****@192.168.1.106:5984/_users/org.couchdb.user:jerk
HTTP/1.1 404 Object Not Found
X-CouchDB-Body-Time: 0
X-Couch-Request-ID: ddccff4105
Server: CouchDB/2.1.1 (Erlang OTP/18)
Date: Fri, 30 Mar 2018 08:35:10 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 41
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
```

Comment: It is more efficient to query for the exact user, so you don't have to load the complete user database into memory with every keystroke: curl -u admin:admin -X GET http://localhost:5984/_users/org.couchdb.user:username
– don't forget to `encodeUriComponent()` the username, though!